# ArcPy script to iteratively solve routes

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, network-analyst, route

I have an Excel file with route starting and ending points, their co-ordinates and a name for that route. I've tried writing the following ArcPy script to iteratively solve each route and add the route result to a new polyline feature class.

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd

filepath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #r"C:\Users\temp.xlsx"
netdataset = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) #r"C:\Users\network\ND"
envpath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)#r"C:\Users\scratch"
rtlyr = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) #'route1'
output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4) + ".shp" #route.shp

if arcpy.CheckExtension("Network") == "Available":
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Network")
else:
    arcpy.AddError("Network analyst license unavailable")

arcpy.env.workspace = envpath
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
df = pd.read_excel(filepath)
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(26917) #NAD '83 UTM Zone 17N
arcpy.MakeRouteLayer_na(netdataset,rtlyr,"Length")

if not arcpy.Exists(output):
 arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(envpath,output,"POLYLINE","#","DISABLED","DISABLED",spatial_reference=sr)
else:
    pass

''' df structure
               Name                 X1    Y1    X2    Y2
   0    'First Rd - Second Rd'     ...   ...   ...   ...
   1    'Second Rd - Third Rd'     ...   ...   ...   ...

   (X1,Y1) are the from points, (X2,Y2) are the to points
'''

for i in range(len(df)):
    pointGeoList = []
    OPoint,DPoint = arcpy.Point(),arcpy.Point()
    OPoint.X,OPoint.Y,DPoint.X,DPoint.Y = df['X1'][i],df['Y1'][i],df['X2'][i],df['Y2'][i]
    OPointGeo,DPointGeo = arcpy.PointGeometry(OPoint,sr),arcpy.PointGeometry(DPoint,sr)
    pointGeoList.extend([OPointGeo,DPointGeo])
    tmpPts = "stops.shp"

    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(pointGeoList,tmpPts)
    arcpy.AddLocations_na(rtlyr,"Stops",tmpPts)
    arcpy.Solve_na(rtlyr,"SKIP","TERMINATE")
    if int(arcpy.GetCount_management(output).getOutput(0)) == 0:
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(rtlyr + "\Routes",output) #
    else:
        arcpy.Append_management(rtlyr + "\Routes",output,"NO_TEST")
```

When I run the above script, the first route is created as expected but the subsequent routes have increasingly more stops than I want. That is, Route 1 might list 2 stops, Route 2 will list 4 stops, Route 3 six stops etc.  The behaviour I want is to have each individual route inserted into the feature class, not to have 1 feature representing all routes.

I've thought about using an InsertCursor to add the rows, but that's failed as well. Ultimately, I'd like the output to resemble the following for each route:

Route_Copy.shp Attribute Table
[image: Attribute Table Sample]

Obviously in the above table, i'd prefer to see the actual stop names (i.e "First Rd - Second Rd") over "Location 1 - Location 2".

Answer (score 0):

You have not read the help file for your [Add Locations](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/add-locations.htm) tool and understood the default behaviour of the tool. You must get better at reading the parameter section and not *ignoring* the default parameters. By ignoring the `append` parameter you have accepted the default setting which is to APPEND. Thus it keeps adding stops to the stops sub-layer of your route layer. You need to set that to CLEAR so on the next iteration of your loop the old stops are removed and your new stops are inserted.

Comment: That fixed the issue with append, thank you. But I'm still unable to add the RouteName i'm after. In the excel file, there's a column i'd like to reference for the route name. It doesn't seem to me that NAClassFieldMappings will work, so how could I go about it?

Comment: Because the various parameters of the tool can be quite complex, especially if you want to run it as a script I would do the following: run the tools manually in ArcMap and get it to do what you want, in your case include the route name, then from the geoprocessing history panel right click on the tool that had run and copy as snippet. Paste that into a text file and you can understand the syntax.